# c++ reference field in a class throw the constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference

I have this class:

```
typedef int ID;
typedef int Salary;
class Worker {
protected:
ID id;
Salary& salary;

public:
Worker();
Worker(ID Id, Salary Salary) {
        this->id=Id;
        this->salary=salary;
    }
```

.
   .
   .
   }

and this one:

```
class WSalary : public Worker {
public:
    WSalary(ID Id, Salary& Salary) {
        this->id=Id;
        this->salary=Salary;
    }
.
.
.
}
```

and I have this error in the constructor

> uninitialized reference member 'Worker::salary' [-fpermissive]

I want to put in the `WSalary` class a field (called salary) that has the same address in the field "salary" in the class worker.. so when I change the salary in the worker class it would change automatically in the `WSalary` class.

whats the solution?
thanks

Comment: C++ requires `const` and `reference` members *must* be initialized in an *constructor initialization list*. You have none. And no good will come from `Salary Salary` as a parameter, much less as a valid initializer for a reference member.

Answer (score 1):

In your worker example you are trying to bind a value to a non-const reference. This would create a dangling reference and is not a good idea. Just store a value in the class instead of a reference or pass a reference as the constructor argument and use the initialization list.

In `WSalary` you need to use the initialization list:

```
WSalary(ID id, Salary& s) : id(id), salaray(s) {}
```

Or call the constructor of the base (should you fix it to accept a reference):

```
WSalary(ID id, Salary& s) : Worker(id, s) {}
```

In C++11 you also just re-use the `Worker` constructor in the derived class using this syntax:

```
using Worker::Worker;
```

Comment: when I use "WSalary(ID id, Salary& s) : id(id), salaray(s) {}"
I get this error: "- class 'WSalary' does not have any field named'salary' "
and the same for id... why ? it should iherit it from the Worker..

Answer (score 0):

Use initialisation list:

```
WSalary(ID Id, Salary& Salary) : id(Id), salary(Salary)
{
}
```

instead of

```
WSalary(ID Id, Salary& Salary) {
                 this->id=Id;
             this->salary=Salary;
}
```

Comment: The `Worker` example is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

If the indirection is intentional, then use a pointer.

---

A reference cannot be made to refer to something else, once it's been initialized.

This means that a reference member generally prohibits assignment for the class, and that it cannot be initialized by assignment.

Pointers, in contrast, can be made to point elsewhere by assignment.